# Is it necessary to reset the fd_set between select system call?

Tags: c, unix

I am facing a problem using the select function in Unix.

I have a server that waits for for a connection. First I add the listening socket file descriptor `listener` to the fd_set `readfds` using `FD_SET(listener, readfds)` and then I use that in `select()`.

When I get a connection, I call `accept()` and set the `readfds` in select with the accepted file descriptor and start receiving the data from connection. However, when I check the code in strace, The select doesn't show the listener in the `readfds` while `select()` is executing a second time.

Do I need to set the listener file descriptor again using `FD_SET(listener, readfds)` before calling `select()` again?

Thanks.

Comment: Also not that on Linux the timeout value can be modified and so will also need to be re-initialized.  The standard permits this but its uncommon in other flavors of unix.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes (it is necessary to reset the `fd_set` between `select()` system calls).

It is a nuisance, but they act as input/output parameters; they are read by and modified by the system call.  When [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) returns, the values have all been modified to reflect the set of file descriptors ready.  So, every time before you call `select()`, you have to (re)initialize the `fd_set` values.

Answer (score 3):

Jonathan is correct.  You need to do the following everytime:

```
set readFDs
set writeFDs
set errorFDs
select(count_of_FDs, readFDs, writeFDs, errorFDs, timeout)
```