# ELI5 Python Module "select" and "selectors"

Tags: python, sockets, select, css-selectors

I've been toying around with using the "socket" module and writing small servers. Now, I
stumbled upon the "select" and "selectors" library. I've been trying to wrap my head around what they do, but haven't found any explanation that is dumbed down enough for me.
Could anybody just eli5 it to me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Those modules work with the operating system's `select` system call, which is described in some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544621/why-is-select-used-in-linux

Comment: What does "eli5" mean?